# Looking for a book: Modelling of Macro Ecconomics with Differential Equations (maybe Difference Equations, maybe recurrences)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, recurrence-relations, book-recommendation

I would like to see the theory behind this modelling: https://sourceforge.net/projects/minsky/
But I can not find a good book to start. There are some youtube videos but he is not getting into the math parts.I would like a book with good math background, it could be also papers. 
Any suggestions?